# Wordpress + jScrollPane

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jscrollpane

Good evening, i'm trying to use jScrollPane in a Wordpress template and i'm going crazy, always shows a "non-skinned" scrollbar...

This code is loaded in the header.php, .portfolio-post-content contains only text:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() {
            $('.portfolio-post-content').jScrollPane();
        });
</script>
```

The element in style.css:

```
.portfolio-post-content { width:130px; float:left; overflow: auto; height: 500px; }
```

The HTML out:

```
    <!-- Main Page Content Begin -->

    <div id="main"> 

      <div id="page-content" class="portfolio-container main-container-single-portfolio" style="position:relative;">

        <div class="container sidebar-left single-project">    

          <!-- Media Begin --> 
          <div class="portfolio-post-media twelve columns"></div>
          <!-- Media End -->        

          <!-- Content Begin -->       
          <div class="portfolio-post-content four columns">text...</div>
          <!-- Content End -->
```

The header file loads jScrollPane.css before the other .js files.
It sounds like a problem related to the nested div elements.

Thanks,

Comment: try to set height of .portfolio-container pragmatically before applying jscrollPane

Comment: Nothing change, always the non-skinned scroller. If i try to "force" the upper level div's height the scroll appears in all the container. I need the scroll only in the content.

I have also tried to add a dedicated outside
<div class="portfolio-post-content four columns">text...</div>
but nothing, the same non-skinned scroll.

Comment: you added styles of jScrollPane to the page?

Comment: Yes, of course. And loaded before the js

Comment: this is the page, maybe it can help to understand the mistake:
http://www.radiospeck.it/barchitects/en/portfolio/castello-di-lispida-luxury-manor/
and the div where i need the skinned scroll is:
<div class="portfolio-post-content four columns">

Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

    $(function() {
        $('.portfolio-post-content.four.columns').jScrollPane();
    });
</script>
```

2: http://www.radiospeck.it/barchitects/wp-content/themes/spacing/js/jquery.mousewhell.js?ver=3.4.2

Not loaded

3:

```
.portfolio-post-content.four.columns {
   height: 200px;
}
```

you can test with:

```
jQuery('.portfolio-post-content.four.columns').css({
    height: '200px'
}).jScrollPane();
```

Comment: Thanks salexch, i dont know if it's the correct way, if i load in .js file:

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.portfolio-post-content.four.columns').css({height: '200px'}).jScrollPane();
    });

the skinned-scroll appear correctly. Is it the only way?

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery('.portfolio-post-content.four.columns').css({height: '200px'}).jScrollPane(); });`

Comment: jScrollPane wont be applied if content is shorter that the container, I set height 200px for example only

Comment: No ok, i understand this, but if don't load this:
jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery('.portfolio-post-content.four.columns'‌​).css({height: '500px'}).jScrollPane(); });
the scroll is not correctly loaded.
The question was, is it necessary?

Comment: sure, cause js is loaded in the header, before the dom is ready, and jScrollPane needs the elemes exists in DOM to make calculations